# How to make a PL/SQL program to update Student Fees when status is active?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am a newbie in PL/SQL and i have a table called ***STUDENT***, and it contains the following columns: **REGNO, NAME, FNAME, DOMICILE, FEES, STATUS**.
what i want to do is when a new record is created and if the student domicile for example `DOMICILE = 'TEXAS'` and `STATUS = 'ACTIVE'` then i want to give 50% Discount in **FEES**.
Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MYTRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT ON STUDENT
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :NEW.DOMICILE = 'TEXAS' AND :NEW.STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN
UPDATE STUDENT SET FEES = FEES - 0.50 * FEES;
END IF;
END MYTRIGGER;
/
```

the trigger gets created but it does not work properly..
example:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES(1,'MARK','SMITH','TEXAS',5000,'ACTIVE');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM STUDENT;

     REGNO NAME                           FNAME                          DOMICILE                          FEES STATUS
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------- --------------------
         1 MARK                           SMITH                          TEXAS                                5000 ACTIVE

SQL> INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES(2,'JAMES','FORD','TEXAS',5000,'ACTIVE');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES(3,'SAM','MILLER','NEW JERSEY',5000,'ACTIVE');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM STUDENT;

     REGNO NAME                           FNAME                          DOMICILE                          FEES STATUS
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------- --------------------
         1 MARK                           SMITH                          TEXAS                                2500 ACTIVE
         2 JAMES                          FORD                           TEXAS                                5000 ACTIVE
         3 SAM                            MILLER                         NEW JERSEY                           5000 ACTIVE

SQL>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: "it does not work properly": please explain what you mean by this. If  you get an error, please edit your question to include the full details of the error.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Okay i edited the question, you can check the example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `update` statement there, all you need is just to set new value to :NEW.FEES:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MYTRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT ON STUDENT
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :NEW.DOMICILE = 'TEXAS' AND :NEW.STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN
  :NEW.FEES := 0.50 * :NEW.FEES;
END IF;
END MYTRIGGER;
/
```

Comment: Well it gave the following error: ```Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> show error;
Errors for TRIGGER MYTRIGGER:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/13     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the
         following:
         := . ( @ % ; indicator
         The symbol ":= was inserted before "=" to continue.

SQL>```

Comment: @BHS sorry, fixed a typo - added ':'

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger is working just fine as it is written. But,  obviously not as to what you want  nor expected. What you want is lower by 1/2 the fees of the incoming row. However it is your expectation that is wrong. What your update statement actually does is lowering the fees by 1/2 for **ever existing** row in the table. Since the incoming row does not exist yet it does NOT participate in the update. That is why it appears to work on some but not all inserts.(Actually I was surprised as I expected an "ORA-04091: table is mutating..." exception). The reason for this is that your Update statement does not have a WHERE clause so it updates every row. See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fd15fe5479dad3e1e9ae3e182f233408) a fiddle that shows what is happening by displaying the table after each insert to see just what that statement actually did. Often a useful technique when results are not as expected.  @SayanMalakshinov is correct: Do not update instead just do an assignment.

```
:new.fees := :new.fees * .5;
```